# PowerShell Script to Enable Multi-Geo for a tenant

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-teams, exchange-server, onedrive

We can assign new Geo location to tenant using web UI. Is it possible to do that using PowerShell command. if yes pls elaborate the Ans and if possible attach the script. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com

# Get the current Geo location
Get-SPOSite -Identity https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com

# Assign a new Geo location
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com -GeoLocation "NewGeoLocation"
```

Replace "yourtenant" with the name of your SharePoint Online tenant and "NewGeoLocation" with the name of the new Geo location you want to assign.

Comment: Got this error 

Set-SPOSite : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'GeoLocation'.
At line:3 char:53
+ ... et-SPOSite -Identity https://abcd.sharepoint.com -GeoLocation "CAN"
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-SPOSite], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetSite